# Journey Builder specific sends based on Data Extension record

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to see which specific records had sends associated with them in Journey Builder?

I have a journey which allows for re-entry's anytime based on cases a contact has submitted.  I'd like to be able to report back on not just the contact key but the PK which in this case is a SalesForce object ID.

Basically, a certain subscriber may have received 3 emails from Journey Builder out of the 5 records they have in a data extension.  I'd like to see which of the 3 records entered the journey based on the contact filters.

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding your problem. Are you saying you have a single data extension that gets evaluated for journey entries, and you may have multiple records of a subscriber for entry, but not all get entered, and you want to know which records actually entered the journey? Is this because someone might qualify to enter while they're still mid-journey and are denied?

Comment: Close.  The data extension catches cases(PK) with contacts associated to them.  There can be multiple unique cases with the same contact record.  Only some of the records are entered into the journey based on contact filters (in this case, it's case status).  So, I need to be able to see which records are actually entering the journey vs. just the contacts entering the journey, which I can easily see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add a new boolean field like "entered_journey" to your entry data extension, and run an Update Contact activity to change that field from false to true on entry.